# Was anyone in Orbán's circle reported w/ clear & convincing evidence to have engaged in compelling adverse interest w/ the anecdotal "carrot & stick"?

Tags: government, crime, corruption, hungary

Has there been any cases where, say, a video recording or audio recording stood as manifest proof of anyone within Fidesz, people with close ties thereto, NER or his family to have offered the stick and the carrot, or engaged in blackmail and bribery or either of the two since the foundation of Fidesz in 1989?

News reports or court decisions asserting to first hand knowledge of such content is sufficient, but would be even more interesting to see any case reported with the audio and/or video.